# Display data in modal from query

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this table with data and a link to display detail into modal

```
<td><a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href="#modal_detail" id="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">Detail</a></td>
```

and this is the modal

```
<div id="modal_detail" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h3>Detail Product</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">            
        <div id="modalContent" style="display:none;">
        Here i want to display data from query about the detail of a product (name, price etc)      
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the php file

```
if(isset($_GET['detail'])) {
    include_once('../libs/class.database.php');
    $k = new Database();
    $link=$k->connect(); 
    $query = $link->query("SELECT name,price FROM products ORDER BY date_created ASC");
    $result=$query->fetchAll();
}
```

for the javascript is like below

```
$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function() {
    var id_beli = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'controller/modalPembelian.php',
        data: 'detail=' + id_beli,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#modal_detail').show();
            $('#modalContent').show().html(data); //this part to pass the var
        }
    });
});
```

My Question is how to display the data from query in the php file (product detail) int o the modal window. The modal just fine, it can show and hide, but the data arent there.

I have tried many ways and search for tutorials but it still the same.

Can anyone show me some example how to display the data using ajax into twitter bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `find()` and place the `data` to `html()`

```
success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   modal.find('#modalContent').html(data);
}
```

Full description here: [Using Bootstrap Modal with AJAX to import data from MySQL](http://thecomputerstudents.com/web/using-bootstrap-modal-ajax-import-data-mysql/)

Comment: The download link is not working on given link. Account is suspended due to heavy traffic. Please fix the link. I found tutorial is very good. Voted Up.

Comment: Download this from GDrive https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Xbq5LIkPeAWjBKNDNIWkpmS2c

Answer (score 1):

check out [jschr's bootstrap modal](http://jschr.github.com/bootstrap-modal/)

its a bootstrap modal plugin that allows you to insert data into the modal using ajax calls, and also displays a loading image while we wait for the data to be retrieved.

another way that I'm just thinking about would be to use the events to try and load the data, this is an example and not 100% tested, but I believe it should work

```
$('#modal_detail').on('show', function(){
  var id_beli = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#modalContent').html('Loading..')

  $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'controller/modalPembelian.php',
      data: 'detail=' + id_beli,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#modalContent').html(data); //this part to pass the var
      }
  });
})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: understandable.. I'll update my answer to be more descriptive